# Output smaller than expected when converting HTML/CSS to PDF using Select.PDF or HiQPDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I am trying to use HTML/CSS to generate a form which will then be converted to a PDF.

The problem I am having is that I want the output to be exactly 8 inches wide.  The result I am getting is roughly 5.125 inches wide.

I first tried this using Select.PDF.  When I couldn't get it to work correctly I looked for another option and found HiQPDF.  Both of them generate the same scaled down output.

Since both products are giving me the same result, it makes me think I have done something incorrectly.  However, if I open the HTML in Chrome and have it print to PDF, I get the results I expect.

Here is the HTML/CSS.  Sizes are measured in points assuming the standard 72 points per inch.  I have also tried doing the measurements in inches.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: white;
                width: 576pt;
            }

            div {
                background-color: transparent;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #231f20;
                color: #231f20;
            }



            #buyer {
                border-width: 1.5pt .5pt .5pt 1.5pt;
                width: 332pt;
                min-height: 18pt;
                clear: left;
                float: left;
            }

            #buyerLabel {
                color: #231f20;
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 6pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 4pt;
                top: 2pt;
            }

            #buyerData {
                color: black;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 14pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 37pt;
                top: 0;
            }


            #phone {
                border-width: 1.5pt .5pt .5pt .5pt;
                width: 143pt;
                min-height: 18pt;
                float: left;
            }


            #phoneLabel {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 6pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 4pt;
                top: 2pt;
            }

            #phoneData {
                color: black;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 14pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 37pt;
                top: 0;
            }



            #date {
                border-width: 1.5pt 1.5pt .5pt .5pt;
                width: 96pt;
                min-height: 18pt;
                float: left;
                clear: right;
            }


            #dateLabel {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 6pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 4pt;
                top: 2pt;
            }

            #dateData {
                color: black;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 14pt;
                position: relative;
                left: 37pt;
                top: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=buyer>
            <div id=buyerLabel>BUYER(S)</div>
            <div id=buyerData>Roger Rabbit</div>
        </div>
        <div id=phone>
            <div id=phoneLabel>PHONE</div>
            <div id=phoneData>(606) 555-5555</div>
        </div>
        <div id=date>
            <div id=dateLabel>DATE</div>
            <div id=dateData>2/28/2019</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is sample C# code I am using to process it.  In this example I am using Select.PDF.  Initially I didn't set any of the options other than the page size.  I added the others later hoping they might correct the problem.

```
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
    converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.Letter;
    converter.Options.MarginLeft = 0;
    converter.Options.MarginRight = 0;
    converter.Options.AutoFitWidth = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.AutoFit;
    converter.Options.CssMediaType = HtmlToPdfCssMediaType.Print;

    var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes("Sample.html"));

    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
    doc.Save("Sample.pdf");
```

Comment: A lot of PDF generators create PDFs at 96 dpi not 72. I know I had this problem with PDF tool I was using and it had an option to change this from 96 to 72. Does Select.PDF have such an option? I would recommend using inches (`in`) for print dimensions and using points (`pt`) for print font sizing. you can also set page size in CSS using the `@page` declaration.. i.e. add `@page { size: A4; }` to your CSS

Comment: Thank you.  I actually tried using measurements in inches at one point and still had the same result.  However, I just tried using 96 dpi to measure the size of the body and padded out one of the cells enough to make a full row and it seems to be working.